# Raspberry Pi 2 running raspbian unmounts external hard drive every so often

Tags: mount, samba, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ntfs

I hope this is an ok place to ask this out of all the stack overflow communities there are.

Anyway I have a raspberry pi 2 in my house that I keep around to backup some files and host media files between myself and my roommates. It worked without issue for a long time other than maybe a system lockup or two in which ssh didn't respond or connect for whatever reason. A simple restart fixed that.

I had an external hard drive mounted to the pi and used ajenti and samba to make it visible to windows machines in the house. Worked great for roughly 9 to 10 months.

About 4 weeks ago it started doing an odd thing in which it unmounted the external drive.

It didn't just unmount it thought it mounted a different file location in its place.

The drive/device is at `/dev/sda1` and it has a mount point of `/media`. However sometimes a different random location with a single folder that contains an album that I guess accidentally got transferred to the location when the /media drive unmounted itself.

Running `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /media` immediately fixes the issues and mounts the correct drive. This won't occur for another day or two before it mounts to this other location again.

I've checked that the drive doesn't have any weird partitions that got created some how, NTFS is correctly installed, ajenti under file systems list the correct device and mount point for the drive so it isn't like it is making some weird mount override that I can see. Also there are now cron jobs that could be doing something weird as far as I can tell either.

I pulled the drive and plugged it into my PC to check its health. Everything came back good so it wouldn't appear to be a drive error.

Can anyone potentially shed some light as to why this issue is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Probably power issues. Try connecting the drive to a powered usb hub. Have you lately added something else to the raspberry?

Comment: Is the drive set to mount at boot, and is the Pi rebooting (`uptime`)?

Comment: Did you know there is a raspberry pi [community](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @EightBitTony this is from long ago but the raspberry pi ended up rebooting from time to time for various reasons. Which was fixed with some software updates to other things running on the pi. I ended up looking into mounting at boot. Checked fstab and everything was normal except there was on oddly inserted /dev/sdda1 instead of /dev/sda1. I hadn't messed with fstab from when the issue started unless I did something and don't remember but fixing that extra 'd' character solved the issue. Small oversight on my part. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that using a powered USB 3.0 hub connected to the USB 3.0 port on a Pi 4 fixes several problems with external USB drives.